# Override count in treeview nodes c#

Tags: c#, count, treeview, overriding

I want to override the count in the treeview nodes in the proper ways in order to get the count of nodes by specific text or name. It is possible to do so? Thanks in advance.

For example:

This is how my treeview looks like

[image]

In this case if I use treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Count, I will get 3 which are the number of nodes in the Root.

**I want something like this, treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.CountByText("Folder") which will return me 2, the exact number of nodes(Text = "Folder") exist in the Root node.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

```
public static int CountByText(this TreeView view, string text)
{
   //logic to iterate through nodes and do count
   return count;
}
```

You can then do:

```
var count = treeview.CountByText("Folder");
```

You could pass in the TreeNodeCollection to do it on that also, depending on your preference.

EDIT:

Some quick code to illustrate:

```
    static class Class1
    {
        public static int CountByText(this TreeView view, string text)
        {
            int count = 0;

           //logic to iterate through nodes and do count
            foreach (TreeNode node in view.Nodes)
            {
                nodeList.Add(node);
                Get(node);
            }
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodeList)
            {
                if (node.Text == text)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
           nodeList.Clear();
           return count;
        }

        static List<TreeNode> nodeList = new List<TreeNode>();
        static void Get(TreeNode node)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
            {
                nodeList.Add(n);
                Get(n);
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: What if I want something more specific, like I want to count the Value in the folder? If treeview.CountByText("Value") I think it will give me 3 but actually is 2 base on the example above.

Comment: @overshadow I added some more detail

Comment: @overshadow also if you want 2, not 3 based on value only having 2 unique parents, then simply amend the logic within the method to reflect that. Or amend the extension method to accept a Treenode parameter not tree view.

Comment: Thanks @Jaycee, Then how I call it? Can I call it like this way treeview1.Nodes["Root"].Nodes["Folder"].CountByText("Value") ?

Comment: @overshadow you could if you changed the parameter type to TreeNode.

Comment: And remove the first for loop

Answer (score 1):

This is my modified version base on the code provided by @Jaycee and I hope it helps other

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int CountByText(this TreeNode view, string text)
    {
        int count = 0;

        //logic to iterate through nodes and do count
        foreach (TreeNode node in view.Nodes)
        {
            if (node.Text == text)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```